# Change font-family for fonts.com import in SASS

Tags: css, fonts, sass, font-face

I am trying to make the **hosted fonts.com import** naming a bit nicer for a client. **I can't rename it on fonts.com** as other sites use the same hosted font version, so that is not an option.

I've tried using something like the following code, but as I am here obviously it does not work as planned:

```css
@import url('http://fast.fonts.net/cssapi/pathtohostedcss.css')

@font-face
  font-family: 'Company Medium'
  src: local('Futura LT W01 Medium')
  font-weight: 500
  font-style: normal

@font-face
  font-family: 'Company Heavy'
  src: local('Futura LT W02 Heavy')
  font-weight: bold
  font-style: normal
```

Is there a way to do this in SASS? Not that I am using **indented style** and not SCSS.

Answer (score 0):

I would look in http://fast.fonts.net/cssapi/pathtohostedcss.css, find the @font-face declarations and simply copy and paste them after the import while only changing the font name. Should work, you would be overwriting the original @font-face declarations.

Comment: Ioan-Radu: I've thought about that as well, but that makes the font implementation fully local and that is not an option in this case. What is needed is a way to locally overwrite just the classes supplied by the fonts.com hosted css (as is).